# Problem Plot: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot, simulation

Good morning, I have a problem plotting. In the last 10 lines of the syntax I try to create a plot for the bias but I get the following error: "Error in xy.coords (x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log): 'x' and 'y' lengths differ" It seems that there is an error with the coordinates of the graph and I do not know how to solve it

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

```
# Numero de Simulaciones
M<-10000

# Tamaños de Muestra
n<-c(100,500,1000)

# Parametros
S<-0.9
C<-0.9

# Matriz de resultados

T<-matrix(0,M,9)

colnames(T)<-c("Xbar.100.P1","Xbar.100.P2","Xbar.100.P3",
               "Xbar.500.P1","Xbar.500.P2","Xbar.500.P3",
               "Xbar.1000.P1","Xbar.1000.P2","Xbar.1000.P3")

# Estudio de SimulaciOn
set.seed(1000)

for(h in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:M){
   
    P1<-  rbinom(1,n[h],(0.01*S) + (1−0.01)*(1−C))
    P2<-  rbinom(1,n[h],(0.05*S) + (1−0.05)*(1−C))
    P3<-  rbinom(1,n[h],(0.1*S) + (1−0.1)*(1−C))
 
    
    a<-(3*(h-1)+1)
    b<- 3*h
    

    
    T[j,a:b]<-c(mean(P1)/n[h],mean(P2)/n[h],mean(P3)/n[h])
    
  }
}


# Analisis de Resultados
est<-rep(c("Media"),times=1)
dis<-rep(c("P1","P2","P3"),times=3)
tam<-rep(n,each=3)

sesgo<-colMeans(T)
a1<-c(0.01,0.01,0.01,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.1,0.1,0.1)
a2<-rbind(x)
sesgo_f <- sesgo-a1
variancia<-diag(var(T))
ecm<-variancia+sesgo^2



# Tabla Error Cuadratico Medio

res<-rbind(
  matrix(ecm[dis=="P1"],3,1,byrow=T),
  matrix(ecm[dis=="P2"],3,1,byrow=T),
  matrix(ecm[dis=="P3"],3,1,byrow=T)
)

res<-cbind(
  rep(n,1),
  res
)

colnames(res)<-c("T. de Muestra","Media")
rownames(res)<-rep(c("P1","P2","P3"),each=3)

round(res,4)

ecm



# Tabla Sesgo

res<-rbind(
  matrix(sesgo_f[dis=="P1"],3,1,byrow=T),
  matrix(sesgo_f[dis=="P2"],3,1,byrow=T),
  matrix(sesgo_f[dis=="P3"],3,1,byrow=T)
)

res<-cbind(
  rep(n,2),
  res
)

colnames(res)<-c("T. de Muestra","Media")
rownames(res)<-rep(c("P1","P2","P3"),each=3)

round(res,4)
sesgo_f




# Gr�fico - Error Cuadr�tico Medio

#par(mfrow=c(1,2))


plot(n,ecm[(dis=="P1")&(est=="Media")],ylim=c(0,0.04),
     type="l",col=1,lty=1,lwd=2,
     main="Error Cuadratico Medio",
     xlab="Tamaño de Muestra",
     ylab="Error Cuadratico Medio")

lines(n,ecm[(dis=="P2")&(est=="Media")],
      col=2,lty=2,lwd=2)

lines(n,ecm[(dis=="P3")&(est=="Media")],
      col=3,lty=4,lwd=2)


legend("topright",c("P1","P2","P3"),col=c(1,2,3),lty=c(1,2,4),lwd=2)


# Grafico - Sesgo


#est<-rep(c("Media"),times=1)
#dis<-rep(c("P1","P2","P3"),times=3)
#tam<-rep(n,each=3)

plot(n,sesgo_f[(dis=="P1")&(est=="Media")],ylim=c(0,0.04),
     type="l",col=1,lty=1,lwd=2,
     main="Error Cuadratico Medio",
     xlab="Tamaño de Muestra",
     ylab="Error Cuadratico Medio")

lines(n,sesgo_f[(dis=="P2")&(est=="Media")],
      col=2,lty=2,lwd=2)

lines(n,sesgo_f[(dis=="P3")&(est=="Media")],
      col=3,lty=4,lwd=2)


legend("topright",c("P1","P2","P3"),col=c(1,2,3),lty=c(1,2,4),lwd=2)
```

Comment: Help us to help you: please provide a *minimal* working example.  There is no call to function `xy.coords` in your (lengthy) code source, so please identify the line on which the error occurs.  When you've done that, we need the input data to that same function call: all the earlier derivation is irrelevant.  Please include the input data by using `dput()` or `dput(head())`.

Comment: Check the errors of your code in the console. I get about 10 errors in your code.

Comment: @TarJae my syntax only has an error in the final plot, the rest runs normal.

Comment: Thank you all, you can fix it, I was missing a comma